# Cannot get length of undefined - Vuetify dataTable

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am experimenting with Vuetify as a frontend for my API.

My API endpoint is `simpleleads.test/api/v1/organisation-type` and it returns the following response:

```
{
  data: [{
      id: 3,
      name: "Accident Management",
      active: 1,
      created_at: "2018-07-17 09:44:41",
      updated_at: "2018-07-17 09:44:41"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "CMC",
      active: 1,
      created_at: "2018-07-17 09:44:41",
      updated_at: "2018-07-17 09:44:41"
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "Garage",
      active: 1,
      created_at: "2018-07-17 11:44:41",
      updated_at: "2018-07-17 13:44:41"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Insurance",
      active: 1,
      created_at: "2018-07-17 09:44:41",
      updated_at: "2018-07-17 09:44:41"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Solicitors",
      active: 1,
      created_at: "2018-07-17 09:44:41",
      updated_at: "2018-07-17 09:44:41"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Vehicle Repairs",
      active: 1,
      created_at: "2018-07-17 09:44:41",
      updated_at: "2018-07-17 09:44:41"
    }
  ],
  links: {
    first: "http://simpleleads.test/api/v1/organisation-type?page%5Bnumber%5D=1",
    last: "http://simpleleads.test/api/v1/organisation-type?page%5Bnumber%5D=1",
    prev: null,
    next: null
  },
  meta: {
    current_page: 1,
    from: 1,
    last_page: 1,
    path: "http://simpleleads.test/api/v1/organisation-type",
    per_page: 30,
    to: 6,
    total: 6
  }
}
```

My Vuetify datatable component is:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="organisationTypes"
            :pagination.sync="pagination"
            :total-items="totalOrganisationTypes"
            :loading="loading"
            class="elevation-1"
        >
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
                <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.created_at }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.updated_at }}</td>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import OrganisationType from '../../models/OrganisationType'
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                totalOrganisationTypes: 0,
                organisationTypes: [],
                loading: true,
                pagination: {},
                headers: [
                    {
                        text: 'Name',
                        align: 'left',
                        value: 'name'
                    },
                    { text: 'Created At', value: 'created_at' },
                    { text: 'Updated At', value: 'updated_at' }
                ]
            }
        },
        watch: {
            pagination: {
                handler () {
                    this.getDataFromApi()
                        .then(data => {
                            this.organisationTypes = data.items
                            this.totalOrganisationTypes = data.total
                        })
                },
                deep: true
            }
        },
        async mounted () {
            this.getDataFromApi()
                .then(data => {
                    this.organisationTypes = data.items
                    this.totalOrganisationTypes = data.total
                })
        },
        methods: {
            getDataFromApi () {
                this.loading = true
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const { sortBy, descending, page, rowsPerPage } = this.pagination

                    let items = this.getOrganisationTypes()
                    const total = items.length

                    if (this.pagination.sortBy) {
                        items = items.sort((a, b) => {
                            const sortA = a[sortBy]
                            const sortB = b[sortBy]

                            if (descending) {
                                if (sortA < sortB) return 1
                                if (sortA > sortB) return -1
                                return 0
                            } else {
                                if (sortA < sortB) return -1
                                if (sortA > sortB) return 1
                                return 0
                            }
                        })
                    }

                    if (rowsPerPage > 0) {
                        items = items.slice((page - 1) * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage)
                    }

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.loading = false
                        resolve({
                            items,
                            total
                        })
                    }, 1000)
                })
            },
            getOrganisationTypes () {
                OrganisationType.get()
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The table component fails to load the data, despite the data being returned to the XHR tab in developer tools. Plus, I get the following error in the console:

> app.js:2658 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'length' of undefined

That error is in reference to this line:

```
var total = items.length;
```

I use https://github.com/robsontenorio/vue-api-query to manage my queries as it works really well with Laravel and an associated package

```
import Model from './Model'
import Organisation from "./Organisation";

export default class OrganisationType extends Model {
    resource() {
        return 'organisation-type'
    }

    organisationTypes() {
        return this.hasMany(Organisation)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with this, please?

Comment: What's your `OrganisationType` file?

Comment: Just added to my answer

Comment: It seems to me that your JSON contains `data` key instead of `items` and is missing the `total` key - although you are looking for such key.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `getOrganisationTypes()` doesn't have a `return` statement - so it returns `undefined`, and when you're storing this `undefined` in a variable (`items`), and try to access its (non-exist) property `length`, you gets this error. So, simple change your `getOrganisationTypes()` method to:

```
async getOrganisationTypes() {
  return await OrganisationType.get();
}
```

And inside the caller method:

```
getOrganisationTypes().then(items => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It now says that the promise is pending...

Comment: And? What's the problem?

Comment: The table still isn't populated

Comment: Your method doesn't wait for the ajax complete. I edited my answer.